# Appending string to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to append table name dynamically to SQL Server stored procedure, but I get an error:

> couldn't find the stored procedure 's'

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON    
GO     

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[atest_demo_sp]    
    @name varchar(10)     
AS     
BEGIN     
    Declare @tname nvarchar    
    Declare @sql nvarchar    

    set @tname = @name           
    Set @sql = 'select * from ' + convert(varchar(10), @tname)    

    -- select @sql     
    execute sp_executesql @sql     
END
```

Comment: What's the command you used to call atest_demo_sp?

Comment: error message you posted ,doesn't relate to the code you are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the `set @tname = @name`, no need to assign the `varchar` to `nvarchar` here. Avoid the `@tname` variable and directly use `@name` in the `SET` statement since it is already `varchar`.

Hope the `@name`'s first character only assigning to `@tname`. Also need to define the `@sql` to some length.

Use the below statement, it will work:

```
Declare @sql varchar(100);
Set @sql = 'select * from ' + @name
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **explicitly define** a **length** for your string variables!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO    
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON    
GO     

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[atest_demo_sp]    
    @name varchar(10)     
AS     
BEGIN     
    Declare @tname nvarchar(200)    -- DEFINE A LENGTH HERE !!!
    Declare @sql nvarchar(200)      -- DEFINE A LENGTH HERE !!!

    set @tname = @name           
    Set @sql = N'select * from ' + convert(nvarchar(10), @tname)    

    -- select @sql     
    execute sp_executesql @sql     
END
```

Otherwise, your variables `@tname` and `@sql` will be **exactly 1 character** long! Probably *not* what you want!

See this blog post for more details: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Also, as a side note: either pick `varchar` (non-Unicode), or use `nvarchar` (Unicode) - but don't mix the two. And *if* you use `nvarchar`, you should **always** use the `N'...'` notation for assigning string literals.